# Python UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 74: invalid start byte

Tags: python, byte, hbase

I have some data in the hbase stored as bytes and strings combined delimited by \x00 padding.

So the row in my hbase looks like:-

```
00:00:00:00:00:00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00U\xEF\xA0\xB00\x002\x0040.0.2.1\x00
```

There is value corresponding to this row (key) which is 100.

Row description:-

```
00:00:00:00:00:00 - This is mac address and is a string 
\x80\x00\x00\x00U\xEF\xA0\xB00 - This is the time which is saved as bytes
2 - this is customer id number stored as string
40.0.2.1 - this is store ID stored as string
```

I have used star base module to connect python to it's stargate server.

Here is my code snippet to connection to starbase and to the hbase table, and try fetching out the value of that row:-

```
from starbase import Connection
import starbase

C = Connection(host='10.10.5.2', port='60010')
get_table =  C.table('dummy_table')
mac_address = "00:00:00:00:00:00"
time_start = "\x80\x00\x00\x00U\xEF\xA0\xB00"
cus_id = "2"
store_id = "40.0.2.1"

create_query = "%s\x00%s\x00%s\x00%s\x00" % (mac,time_start,cus_id,store_id)

fetch_result = get_table.fetch(create_query)
print fetch_result
```

Expected output is:-

```
100
```

You don't have to worry about the starbase connection and it's methods. They work just fine if everything was a string but now since time is converted into bytes, it is giving me error:-

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 74: invalid start byte
```

Just in case you need to see the output of create_query when I print it:-

```
00:00:1E:00:C8:36▒U▒v▒130.0.2.6
```

I would highly appreciate some help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
time_start = "\\x80\\x00\\x00\\x00U\\xEF\\xA0\\xB00"
```

\x is escape sequence for hex values,

```
create_query = "%s\x00%s\x00%s\x00%s\x00" % (mac,time_start,cus_id,store_id)
```

was converting time_start to string. And since x80 is not valid utf-8,it was throwing an error.

Comment: I tried your suggesstion but It didn't work. It doen't give any error but it gives None as results.

Comment: Try replacing all the \x00 with \\x00 in create_query.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your database doesn't support storing bytes in these fields; perhaps you must store strings.

One approach would be to convert your bytes into base64 strings before storing them in the database. For example:

```
>>> from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
>>> b64encode("\x80\x00\x00\x00U\xEF\xA0\xB00")
'gAAAAFXvoLAw'
>>> b64decode(_)
'\x80\x00\x00\x00U\xef\xa0\xb00'
```

Comment: Hbase does support storing bytes. Infact storing data in bytes gets you much faster result scans in hbase than strings. That was the reason to store data in bytes form over strings.

Comment: @Ray, well, which line of code does the error occur on? If you're printing raw bytes, wouldn't it implicitly convert to unicode?